# Amazon SES-like service to implement a service like Mailchimp

Tags: amazon-ses

I run this service called [Mailbrew](https://mailbrew.com/) and use **Amazon SES** to send emails.

In the future I would like to offer the possibility for users to set up their own newsletters through the service and **send them from their own email address** (with custom domains and all) — like Mailchimp does.

Here are my questions:

1. Do you know if this is possible with SES itself? It seems not since there is a limit of 10k registered domains/emails per AWS region and registering a domain for sending is a tedious process.
2. Do you know of any other managed service that would allow me to send emails from custom domains in a managed way without having to setup my own email servers?

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know if this is possible with SES itself?

Yes. it is.

> It seems not since there is a limit of 10k registered domains/emails per AWS region

You will have to open a support case to extend the registration limit; this is not a technical limitation.

> and registering a domain for sending is a tedious process.

That depends; we have mostly automated this procedure.

> Do you know of any other managed service that would allow me to send emails from custom domains in a managed way without having to setup my own email servers?

Yes, there are a few, like SendGrid (on Azure). SES is quite simple, though. If you think of integrating this for a larger quantity of domains, I would recommend to stick with it.

Comment: do you know if it is possible to add and remove domains programmatically to SES?

Comment: Yes, it is supported. Adding, removing, state check and management is implemented.